# Can I erase Windows 8 and install Ubuntu instead?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation

I recently bought a new laptop computer and have been unable to install Ubuntu alongside the Windows 8 operating system. I used to be able to install Ubuntu alongside a Windows OS but with Windows 8 that's no longer possible or too difficult for me to master. I don't really need Windows so I just want to wipe the disk and do a clean install of Ubuntu. What I want to know is if this is easy - as it used to be - or is it just as complicated as installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 8. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo thinkpad. Just had to install from LiveUSB and selected first option. Worked perfectly. Now a dedicated Ubuntu 13.10 laptop

Answer (score 0):

As far as you do not want to dual boot it should be a piece of cake. When you will boot from live usb/cd just follow basic installation steps and when it will come to "Installation type" you should choose "Replace Windows with Ubuntu" option rather then "Install alongside" one. So take your courage and do it!